# Powershell not exiting

Tags: apache, powershell, tomcat, powershell-2.0

```
cd "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\bin"
.\shutdown.bat
.\startup.bat
```

I have above command in powershell file, but problem is that, powershell has not exited after .\startup.bat.

So, for solving this issue i have used following command, but then apache is not working for me

```
START "C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.67\bin\startup.bat"
```

Comment: If you omit the .\startup.bat call does the powershell terminate? If yes, you should post the content of it...

Comment: yes, after omitting .\startup.bat, powershell terminate. sorry, i don't understand your point

Comment: well, the startup.bat probably doesnt terminate so you should post the content here

Comment: setlocal

rem Guess CATALINA_HOME if not defined
set "CURRENT_DIR=%cd%"
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
cd ..
set "CATALINA_HOME=%cd%"
cd "%CURRENT_DIR%"
:gotHome
if exist "%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat" goto okHome
echo The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
echo This environment variable is needed to run this program
goto end
:okHome

set "EXECUTABLE=%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\catalina.bat"

Comment: rem Check that target executable exists
if exist "%EXECUTABLE%" goto okExec
echo Cannot find "%EXECUTABLE%"
echo This file is needed to run this program
goto end
:okExec

rem Get remaining unshifted command line arguments and save them in the
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=
:setArgs
if ""%1""=="""" goto doneSetArgs
set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%CMD_LINE_ARGS% %1
shift
goto setArgs
:doneSetArgs

call "%EXECUTABLE%" start %CMD_LINE_ARGS%

:end

Answer (score 0):

If `startup.bat` does not exit, start it with [`Start-Process`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh849848.aspx) *without* the `-wait` parameter.

```
Start-Process .\startup.bat
```

(use the relative path in the working directory, not a global path)